# How to permanently hide a hidden system tray icon in Windows 7 or Windows 8 or Windows 10

Tags: windows, icons, notification-area, desktop-customization

I have an application and it has a system tray icon. I don't want to display it. I hid the notification icon from settings, but it is visible with other inactive icons like the image below;

[image: hidden notification icons]

But I want to remove the icon from there also, so that the icon won't appear anymore. How can I do this? Is there a solution or a workaround?

Comment: This is entirely up to the application to handle.  An application can generate 100 icons if it is designed to do so.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to kill the icon is to stop the program from running.  You can enable and disable startup programs in the Task Manager (right click the taskbar).

If you want the program to keep running, you'll need to find a setting that the program respects.  If you're lucky it will be in the program's UI, but it may be hidden in the Windows registry, or there may not be any setting at all.